# Redirect edge flow

Tags: modeling, edges, workflow, topology

Beginner's question. I'm working on the low poly version of the model on the left side of the image and I want to understand what's the best way to redirect the edge flow of my model's topology for this particular case. Is there more than one way to do it?

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you're trying to reproduce the obect that is on the left? I would extrude, then bevel the edges to make them round?

Comment: No, actually the object on the left is the high poly version. I'm working on the low poly version so I can bake the normals, but I want to make sure the model has a good topology and edge flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to stick to quads then a good place to start is usually to make a ring of edges around the cuts (yellow)
[image]
But to have a round bevel more contained like in the original model you need more than 2 vertices (blue)
I think I'd do something like this:
[image]

This is assuming you are using a subdivision mod to give the curvature. But like moonboots said I'm not sure you need something that complicated for this since just a few bevels and smooth shading would basically do the same for such a simple shape

Answer (score 2):

I would begin with this plane:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Remove these faces:

[image]

Bevel these edges:

[image]

Then these ones:

[image]

Give it thickness with the *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Topology re-worked, these tris won't cause any artefact or bad shading:

[image]

Comment: So, this is what I initially planned to do, but beveling those edges and consequently creating a bunch of triangles is not a bad practice? Also, by bevelling the corners you created 2 n-gons on the back, this could also be called bad practice, right?

Comment: if it doesn't create any artefact it's ok to use tris and ngons, also I can get rid of them if necessary

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation!